# Error on mount through php "exec"

Tags: php, linux, exec, mount, iscsi

I'm trying to mount an iscsi virtual disk, but if I execute the command through the exec function in php this give me that error: `mount: special device /dev/sdf1 does not exist`.
But if I run the command directly in the console it run well!!
What can I do?
I'm obtaining the `/dev/sdf1` in a good way, and it exists, but only through php doesn't work.

### Thanks

I'm running the command with `sudo` and run it in console as `www-data` user always with `sudo`, so, I suppose that is the same enviroment.

`sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sdf1 /san_disks/RIBS_2`

The sudoers file has this lines:

```
www-data    ALL = (root) /usr/bin/iscsiadm, /bin/mount, /bin/umount
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And it works in console.

Comment: Elaborate "in a good way". Also consider mod_chroot, suexec+fastcgi environment.

Comment: your php code probably doesnt have the right permissions to execute that command, check the previliges for apache, and the user through which it runs.

Comment: do you have safe_mode turned on?

Comment: [Update][1] See my answer. It may be a timing issue.  AFter creating the iSCSI device, it takes a second or so for it to appear.  Adding a pause will allow mount to work. [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465466/exec-doesnt-found-a-file/4465528#4465528

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because "/dev" wasn't updated. I made a sleep(1) and it works!!