# exec doesn't found a file

Tags: php, directory, exec

I'm having problems with the exec php function.
When I do:

```
ls -al /dev/sdf1
```

This doesn't found the archive (ls: cannot access /dev/sdf1: No such file or directory), but if I run this command, in console that show me the information.
What can I do?
That happen even running the php script as a root!!

```
$mountcommand = "ls -al /dev/$unit  2>&1";
exec("$mountcommand", &$mountoutput, &$mountresult);
print_r($mountoutput);
echo "\n$mountcommand\n\n";
```

This is in a forked process

Comment: It works for me.  Show us how you're using it.

Comment: Is Linux running with SELinux enabled?  Or via some other kind of chroot jail?  Actually, now that I think about it, you probably are in a [chroot jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)...

Comment: Starting the script, I do chroot("/"), run as a root, and still nothing!!

Comment: Execute `passthru('ls -la /')` and see what it comes up with.  Is that the `/` directory?  or is it some other directory?

Comment: You don't need the `&` for `$mountoutput` or `$mountresult`.  The function defines those arguments as pass-by-reference itself.

Comment: `chroot('/')` won't break you out of a chroot. I think `chroot('/')` is pretty much always a no-op. You should use @ircmaxell's passthru or `readlink /proc/pid-of-php/root`

Comment: I execute passthru("ls -la /") and it show me all the content of "/", but if I change "/" for "/dev/$unit" it still doesnt work!!

Comment: @ldcl: Try just `/dev` and see if you see that `$unit` in there manually...

Comment: It works, but sdf1 isn't in the list. but if I run the same command in the shell it is

Comment: Maybe still, the PHP process is seeing a chroot's /dev.  Compare the output of  `ls -id /dev` from PHP with `ls -id /dev' from the commandline.  It they(inode #'s) are different then the PHP proc has its own private /dev; if they are the same and the inode isn't 2, it's probably the same /dev; but if the inode is "2" all bets are off.  I'm thinking  sdf1 is a removable volume that only shows up in the "real" /dev.

Comment: Both output are the same! And about sdf1, it is a iscsi drive, with a session started in the same php, is the code run before the ls (here is the source of my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455841/error-on-mount-through-php-exec)

Comment: The outputs of `ls -id /dev` doesn't mean much unless the inode reported was NOT *inode #2*. If they were both some odd number like 142, chances are /dev is the same directory on the webserver and at the commandline. It they are different numbers, they are different dirs. Okay, if the PHP session is responsible for creating /dev/sdf1, then that part(iscsiadm) might be failing.  When PHP runs the command to connect to a target iSCSI dev. Check the return status from the *exec()* call, and capture any messages if you can.  Put <pre> tags around the PHP and see the result in a browser</pre>.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

The disks:

```
frayser@gentoo ~/doc/Answers/src/PHP $ disk

sda     111.790 GB
sdb     233.762 GB
sdc     233.762 GB
sdd     233.762 GB
sde     279.481 GB
------------------
Total:  1092.558 GB
```

Using hde:

```
frayser@gentoo ~/doc/Answers/src/PHP $ l /dev/sde
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 64 Dec  2 13:36 /dev/sde
```

Using PHP:

```
frayser@gentoo ~/doc/Answers/src/PHP $ php lsdev.php 
Z: brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 64 Dec  2 13:36 /dev/sde
```

The script:

```
frayser@gentoo ~/doc/Answers/src/PHP $ cat lsdev.php 
<?php
$z=exec("ls -lr /dev/sde");
print "Z: " . $z . "\n";
?>
```

#### Update

It also works with `ls -al`.
Please show your script.

#### Update 2

Along the lines of the chroot suggestion by ircmaxell: Supposing that /dev, as seen in the PHP process, was a special chroot facsimile of the real one.  And supposing that /dev/sdf1 is a removable device.  The when sdf1(the media) is inserted the system automatically creates the device in the real /dev; but the chroot version isn't updated.  So, to detect this situation look for differences between /dev as seen from PHP and from the commandline.

One test is `ls -id` on /dev(from PHP and the commandline).  This prints the inode of /dev.  Is there a mismatch in inode numbers?

Is /dev/sdf1 removable?  Is it mounted?  If it is mounted; does the PHP process see the mounted filesystem: `ls $mount_point` from PHP it.

There are other chroot tests [listed on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455841/error-on-mount-through-php-exec) and elsewhere; but I haven found many good ones: If a chroot is done correctly, it is hard to detect.

#### Update 3

This may be what is happening: The device (/dev/sdf1) takes a while to appear after it is created; so it is necessary to pause between creating the device and attempting to mount it:

Before: The device is created; but it isn't there...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Logging out of session [sid: 4, target: iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e, portal: 172.16.0.1,3260]
    [1] => Logout of [sid: 4, target: iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e, portal: 172.16.0.1,3260]: successful
    [2] => Logging in to [iface: iface0, target: iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e, portal: 172.16.0.1,3260]
    [3] => Login to [iface: iface0, target: iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e, portal: 172.16.0.1,3260]: successful
    [4] => ls: cannot access /dev/sdg: No such file or directory
)

{ test -b /dev/sdg && sudo iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e -u; sudo iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e -l; ls -al /dev/sdg ;} 2>&1
```

After: Added a 1-second pause, and the device (sdg) is available...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Logging out of session [sid: 5, target: iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e, portal: 172.16.0.1,3260]
    [1] => Logout of [sid: 5, target: iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e, portal: 172.16.0.1,3260]: successful
    [2] => Logging in to [iface: iface0, target: iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e, portal: 172.16.0.1,3260]
    [3] => Login to [iface: iface0, target: iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e, portal: 172.16.0.1,3260]: successful
    [4] => brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 96 Dec 18 05:27 /dev/sdg
)

{ test -b /dev/sdg && sudo iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e -u; sudo iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e -l; sleep 1; ls -al /dev/sdg ;} 2>&1
```

The PHP with the pause ...

```
<pre>
<?php
$unit='sdg';
$reset="test -b /dev/sdg && sudo iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e -u";

$connect="sudo iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2004-08.org.frayser:gen2-dummy.ad4s0.dos.e -l";

$test="ls -al /dev/$unit";

$mountcommand = "{ $reset; $connect; sleep 1; $test ;} 2>&1";
exec("$mountcommand", $mountoutput, $mountresult);
print_r($mountoutput); 
echo "\n$mountcommand\n\n";
?>
</pre>
```

The */etc/sudoers* is configured the same as reported in the previous question about [mount failing from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455841/error-on-mount-through-php-exec).

So add a second or two of sleep() after iscsiadm creates the device. The sleep can be done in PHP instead of in the *exec()* of the shell.

Comment: I present you the [`Works on My Machine Certificate`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html)...  Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks, I have made some proves with the sleep and it looks like it works!! I have to do another proves running the command in other servers by ssh, but thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with a sleep between this code and the code that gave me the "unit"